# SQL query for fetching a value where all but one row matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to come up with a query that will list all the task_groups where all task_names in a group are performed by the 'AUTO' user except for the 'Initial' task which will be manual.
So for the below data I should only see Task_Group '1' in the result and not Task_Group '2'

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QUERY_TST](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [TASK_GROUP] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TASK_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PERFORMED_BY] [varchar](10) NULL
)
--Data
INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(1, 'INITIAL', 'MANUAL')
INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(1, 'TASK1', 'AUTO')
INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(1, 'TASK2', 'AUTO')
INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(1, 'TASK3', 'AUTO')

INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(2, 'INITIAL', 'MANUAL')
INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(2, 'TASK1', 'AUTO')
INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(2, 'TASK2', 'MANUAL')
INSERT INTO QUERY_TST VALUES(2, 'TASK3', 'AUTO')
```

Comment: are there other possible values for `Performed_By` besides `Manual` and `Auto`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you're after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    task_group
FROM query_tst As a
WHERE (
    (NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM query_tst As b
        WHERE (
            (a.task_group = b.task_group) And
            (b.task_name <> 'Initial') And
            (b.performed_by <> 'AUTO')
        )
    ))
);
```

Comment: This one doesnt work because doesnt check if have `'Initial' = 'Manual' `

Comment: This works fine. The op stated that we're concerned with the task_names that aren't 'Initial', which are already known to be completed by the 'Manual' user.

Answer (score 0):

- All task less one is performed by `AUTO`
- The Initial task is perfomen by `MANUAL`

.

```
select [TASK_GROUP]
from [dbo].[QUERY_TST]
GROUP BY [TASK_GROUP]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [PERFORMED_BY] = 'AUTO' AND [TASK_NAME] <> 'Initial' THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)-1
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN [PERFORMED_BY] = 'MANUAL' AND [TASK_NAME] = 'Initial' THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select *
from query_tst as t1
where 
  TASK_NAME = 'initial'
  and not exists (
   select 1
   from query_tst as t2
   where t1.TASK_GROUP = t2.TASK_GROUP 
   and TASK_NAME <> 'initial'
   and PERFORMED_BY = 'manual'
  )
```

Here's a fiddle to show it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9aa8/5